# sed: Search a file and replace a pattern in line

Tags: replace, sed

I want to replace a pattern in some lines:

I have tried

```
sed -i 's/pattern/new-string/g' ./file
```

But this replaces everything in the file.
I want to replace the pattern only on those lines that match another-pattern

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed -i '/another-pattern/s/pattern/new-string/g' ./file
```

This will perform substitution only on lines that match `another-pattern` pattern.